# A* catch if unpossible to reach a point

Tags: java, a-star

i implemented a simple A* and noticed that it does get into an infity loop if all 4 spots around my Character are filled. Current i am stuck how i get it work so they start running into the nearest possible spot. Any Guesses on it? (sorry for the long code)

the A*

```
private Node aStarSearch(int startX, int startY) {
        openList.clear();
        closeList.clear();
        successor.clear();
        Node startNode = new Node(null, startX, startY, 0, 0);
        openList.add(startNode);
        while (openList.size() != 0) {
            // sort the list
            Collections.sort(openList, nodeComperator);
            Node q = openList.remove(0); // get the first object
            int qx = q.x;
            int qy = q.y;
            // start adding the successors
            // left

            Node left = createNeighbor(q, qx - 1, qy);
            if (left != null && !closeList.contains(left))
                successor.add(left);

            // right
            Node right = createNeighbor(q, qx + 1, qy);
            if (right != null && !closeList.contains(right))
                successor.add(right);

            // // down
            Node down = createNeighbor(q, qx, qy - 1);
            if (down != null && !closeList.contains(down))
                successor.add(down);

            // up
            Node up = createNeighbor(q, qx, qy + 1);
            if (up != null && !closeList.contains(up))
                successor.add(up);

            // calc
            for (Node suc : successor) {
                if (suc.x == (int) this.screen.character.mapPos.x
                        && suc.y == (int) this.screen.character.mapPos.y)
                    return suc;
                boolean add = true;
                if (betterIn(suc, openList)) // openList und der
                    add = false;
                if (betterIn(suc, closeList)) // closedList
                    add = false;
                if (add)
                    openList.add(suc);
            }
            closeList.add(q);
        }
        return null;
    }
   private Node createNeighbor(Node parrent, int x, int y) {
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < this.screen.map.width
                && y < this.screen.map.height
                && this.screen.map.mapArray[x][y] != Config.CANTMOVEONPOSITION
                && this.screen.map.mapArray[x][y] != Config.MONSTERSTATE) {
            Node n = new Node(parrent, x, y);
            n.g = calcG(n);
            n.h = calcH(n, (int) this.screen.character.mapPos.x,
                    (int) this.screen.character.mapPos.y);
            return n;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private float calcG(Node n) {
            Node p = n.getParrent();
            return p.g + 1;
        }

        private float calcH(Node n, int targetX, int targetY) {
            float dx = Math.abs(n.x - targetX);
            float dy = Math.abs(n.y - targetY);
            return (float) Math.sqrt((float) (dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
        }

        private boolean betterIn(Node n, List<Node> l) {
            for (Node no : l) {
                if (no.x == n.x && no.y == n.y && (no.g + no.h) <= (n.g + n.h))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

My Node:

```
public class Node {
    public int x, y;
    public float g, h;
    private Node parrent;

    public Node(Node parrent, int x, int y, float g, float h) {
        this.parrent = parrent;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.g = g;
        this.h = h;
    }

    public Node(Node parrent, int x, int y) {
        this.parrent = parrent;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Node getParrent() {
        return parrent;
    }

    public void setParrent(Node parrent) {
        this.parrent = parrent;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // override for a different compare
        return ((Node) o).x == this.x && ((Node) o).y == this.y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // if x and y are the same they are the same
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

If i do use nodes that are blocked but give them a high h they do not walk correct anymore so i dont know whats going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your A* algorithm seems a little bit screwy. But the code's not very clear -- for UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT you repeat the same section (which should be broken out to a method).

It's not clear whether "discovered" nodes are clearly represented -- they should be a Set -- whereas you have "open", "closed" and "successor".

Checking each of your UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT neighbors should be factored out to a method, which you call 4 times with `neighborX` and `neighborY` positions.

There isn't a single clear line which correctly tests whether a given neighbor (it's a neighbor, not a successor) has already been "discovered".

Neither am I sure about the post-processing of successors. Viz:

```
        // calc
        for (Node suc : successor) {
            if (suc.x == (int) this.screen.character.mapPos.x
                    && suc.y == (int) this.screen.character.mapPos.y)
                return suc;
            boolean add = true;
            if (betterIn(suc, openList)) // openList und der
                add = false;
            if (betterIn(suc, closeList)) // closedList
                add = false;
            if (add)
                openList.add(suc);
        }
```

Since you sort "open nodes" on every iteration & pick the probable best, this doesn't really make sense to me & may be erroneous.

Presumably the algorithm should terminate promptly, when all four directions around the character are blocked. Failure to terminate implies that `openList` is not be processed correctly/ or incorrect nodes are being added.

Put some Log4J logging in & write a simple unit-test to verify it's correct behaviour in these conditions.

---

I also recommend rolling the 'createNeighbor', 'discovered check' and 'add to successor list' code into one method `exploreNeighbor( Node q, int offsetX, int offsetY)`.

I've improved style & variable naming somewhat. You should also move towards using getters -- getX(), getY() for example.

```
exploreNeighbor( q, -1, 0);  // left
exploreNeighbor( q, +1, 0);  // right
exploreNeighbor( q, 0, -1);  // up
exploreNeighbor( q, 0, +1);  // down

protected boolean exploreNeighbor (Node parent, int offsetX, int offsetY) {
    int x = q.getX() + offsetX;
    int y = q.getY() + offsetY;
    if (x < 0 || x >= screen.map.width)
        return null;
    if (y < 0 || y >= screen.map.height)
        return false;
    int content = screen.map.mapArray[x][y];
    if (content == Contents.CANTMOVEONPOSITION ||
            content == Contents.MONSTERSTATE) {
        return false;
    }

    // represent Neighbor Position;
    //  
    Node n = new Node(parent, x, y);
    n.g = calcG(n);
    n.h = calcH(n, (int) this.screen.character.mapPos.x,
            (int) this.screen.character.mapPos.y);

    // check if Discovered yet;
    //
    if (discoveredSet.contains( n)) {
        // already queued or visited.
        return false;
    }

    // queue it for exploration.
    openQueue.add( n);
    return true;
}
```

Good luck..

Comment: There are no discovered. I do return the last node and can chain back to the first with the help of the getparrent. I updated the code to the method you told. My fault already had that but used old code here sorry.

Comment: You don't you clear the 'successor' list each iteration, either -- that's almost certainly a bug.

Comment: huh thats a bad bug thanks for that added it. and actually... it did solve the bug ....

Comment: At the time you do your "betterIn" test, you have already removed the current node from "open" -- but not put it in "closed". That's your bug. A single "discovered" set, as I said, would be robust & never have caused this error.

Comment: the not cleaning of the successor was the bug... if there is no path it does return null and it did stuck inside of the successor loop

Comment: I also recommend rolling the 'createNeighbor', 'discovered check' and 'add to successor list' code into one method `exploreNeighbor( Node q, int offsetX, int offsetY)`.